# Google Sheet Auto time stamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I'm trying to auto-populate a cells time ( cell B2 in sheet "leads")

But doesn't seem to run the script successfully. Gives me the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code"`

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var timezone = "GMT-2";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Leads'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var responseArray = ["Time"];
  var questionArray = ["Time"];

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRow();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //get values and place them inside array 
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); //get index position inside the array

  for (var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++) {
    if (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[1]) > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == (headers[0].indexOf(questionArray[i]) + 1)) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!

      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[i]) + 1));
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
      cell.setValue(date);
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried all solutions but nothing seems to give me a successful run.

I want cell B2 to automatically add the time when someone starts to enter data into cell A1

Comment: This won't work when you're running it manually. It relies on the event trigger to get the sheet: `var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Leads');`, this will only work when the trigger runs automatically after an edit to the document.

Comment: Also, this script is very over-complicated if all you're trying to achieve is B2 to add a timestamp when A1 is edited.

Comment: Great, thank you for the advice. Found this script and tried to apply it to my instance .with no luck

Comment: Do you only need a script to update B2 with a timestamp when A1 is updated? That's much more simple than the script you have above.

Comment: Yip, so It's actually for when for the whole of column B when the user starts filling in the date in column A. Its to keep track of when the user started the transaction to keep track of how quickly they finish a deal. new to Excel scripts sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is very over complicated for what you're trying to achieve to be honest.

Try using this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var TIME_ZONE = "GMT-2"; //enter desired timezone
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE, 'MM-dd-yyyy'); //enter desired date format

  //if column A has been edited, set date in same row in column B
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    e.source.getSheetByName('Leads').getRange(row, 2).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Put simply, this code will check that the user has edited column A, if so then it'll put a date value into the same row in column B.

Comment: Thank you for this, how do I set this for Current time instead of date? When I run the script it gives me the following bug "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code""

Comment: @anix89 because this is also running `onEdit(e)` you won't be able to run it manually, it just runs automatically when the sheet is edited. You can change the date format really easily! Just change `'MM-dd-yyyy'` to `'hh:mm:ss'` instead in `var date`. Here's some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for date formatting if you'd like to use any other formats.

Comment: Is there a way that I can do the same function for another sheet in the same workbook so if someone selects approved in column "K" from the drop-down in sheet "leads" the time in sheet "processing" should also get a new time stamp.in column "A". Do I just add another "e.source.getSheetByName ('processing')"

Comment: Yeah should work just fine! If not then you're probably best off opening a new question here and I'm sure myself or someone else here will be able to debug it for you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm getting the same error as @anix89. It's not automatically inserting the timestamp in column B.

Comment: Are you definitely letting it run automatically rather than manually? If running manually it won't be able to find `e` as that is passed when the sheet is edited.